# Modify host in logstash

Tags: logstash

Logstash gets `"host": "server01.staging"`, I want to split the value by `.` and get `"host": "server01", "env": "staging"`. Is there any way to do it?

I tried this:

```
grok {
  match => {
    "message" => ...
    "host" => '\A(?<host>.*?).(?<env>.*)'
  }
  overwrite => [ "message", "host" ]
```

But it still see `"host": "server01.staging"` in the output

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to escape the dot between host and env. In a regex, a non-escaped dot will match any character.

This should work:

```
"host" => '\A(?<host>.*?)\.(?<env>.*)'
```

Comment: No. It does not work too. I tried `"host" => '\A(?<new_host>.*?)\.(?<new_env>.*)'`, but it does change anything, I don't see new fields `new_host` and `new_env`

Comment: That's odd, I got it to work, with `match => {"host" => '\A(?<new_host>.*?)\.(?<new_env>.*)'}` I had the fields `new_host` and `new_env`. I tested it with this conf: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e4597163d7fa8e19c9d150c045d9b739